# Using Xamarin.Forms with Native pages (Xamarin.iOS, UWP)

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, uwp, mvvmcross

I already have a solution which consist of `Xamarin.iOS` and `UWP`. We have multiple views (`Pages`) in both platforms. We are using `MvvmCross`, so we have a common code (`PCL`) which consists of `Viewmodels`, business logic etc. Also, we have separate views (`Pages`) for both `Xamarin.iOS` and `UWP`.

Now I want to add `Xamarin.Forms` support for native pages of both projects so that we have same views for both `Xamarin.iOS` and `UWP`. We need the support of navigation (from `Native` to `Xamarin.Forms` & vice versa). I am navigating through MvvmCross navigation service.

For instance, 
I have `FirstFormView` in `Xamarin.Forms` project.
I have `SecondFormView` in Native project (can be `Xamarin.iOS` or `UWP`).
I have `ThirdFormView` in `Xamarin.Froms` project.

I have navigated to `FirstFormView` (which is staring page of my application)
Now I want to go to `SecondFormView` (which is in native project).
And from SecondFormView  I need to go to `ThirdFormView` which is again in `Xamarin.Forms`

Is it possible to do it `MvvmCross`? If yes, then what steps should we follow to achieve our desired goal.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,

Answer (score 2):

This is possible through the Forms presenters. Take a look at the playground: https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/tree/develop/TestProjects/Playground/Playground.Forms.Droid

Here the views are all Forms, but 1 or 2 are in Native. By using the same solution you should be able to do this.

Comment: is there any example available for UWP as well?

Comment: Yes it is in the same repo

Comment: Yes, but native views are not implemented for uwp in this solution

Comment: Current url to the example is https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/tree/master/TestProjects/Playground/Playground.Forms.Droid

Answer (score 1):

You already have `MvvmCross` in your PCL project, just need to add Xamarin Form pages (XAML) for every page in platform specific project (iOS, UWP). And custom renderers for every platform.

For example:

```
//in xamarin forms pcl project
namespace XFormProject
{
    public class MyXFormPage : ContentPage project
    {

    }
}

// in ios project
namespace XFormProjecy.iOS
{

    [assembly:ExportRenderer(typeof(XFormProject.MyXFormPage), typeof(XFormProject.iOS.MyXFormPageIOS))]
    public class MyXFormPageIOS : PageRenderer // in iOS
    {
        // your ios native page code goes here.
    }
}
```

Read more about [Custom Rederers](https://blog.xamarin.com/customize-your-xamarin-forms-app-with-pages-for-each-platform/)

Hope this helps :)

Comment: How can I navigate from Native page to Xamarin.Form page and vice versa?

Comment: a form page should represent your native page like in the example above. Then you can navigate in forms project just like from one form page to another

Comment: I am navigating through `MvvmCross's` NavigationService.

Comment: For instance, 
I have `FirstFormView` in `Xamarin.Forms` project.
I have `SecondFormView` in Native project (can be `Xamarin.iOS` or `UWP`).
I have `ThirdFormView` in `Xamarin.Froms` project.

I have navigated to `FirstFormView` (which is staring page of my application)

Now I want to go to `SecondFormView` (which is in native project).
And from SecondFormView  I need to go to `ThirdFormView` which is again in `Xamarin.Forms`

Comment: Create XamarinForm page for SecondView and bind it with custom native views in ios and uwp. then you can do the navigation in forms project without communicating to native project.

Comment: What do you mean by views? (controls for pages). Also please can you refer me to any link? Thanks